# How to configure Typescript, Karma, Webpack to run tests in browser

Tags: typescript, webpack, karma-runner

I'm developing a game with Phaser3 and decided that I'd like to add some tests for certain components of my game.

I'm using Typescript 3.3 and webpack 4 as my main tools. I'd like to run tests on browser where some tests might depend on Phaser game library. In past I have used Karma+Jasmine to test Angular.js apps so I figured I would go with that.

After some setup I got tests running but for some reason the test files can't import other modules instead giving error

```
Compiled with warnings.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
✖ ｢wdm｣: 
ERROR in ./src/test/core/EntityFactory.spec.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './foo' in '<path to the project>/src/test/core'
 @ ./src/test/core/EntityFactory.spec.ts 1:0-26
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './foo' in '/<path to the project>/src/test/core'
```

The mentioned `/test/core` directory contains files `EntityFactory.spec.ts` and `foo.ts`. The import is written in the suite as:

```
import thing from './foo';
```

Below are my karma config file and the webpack configuration its using:

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Mar 17 2019 17:03:14 GMT+0200 (EET)
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config').test;

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '**/*.spec.ts'
      // each file acts as entry point for the webpack configuration
    ],

    mime: {
      "text/x-typescript": ["ts", "tsx"],
    },


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
      // '**/*.spec.ts'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
       // add webpack as preprocessor
      '**/*.spec.ts': [ 'webpack' ],

    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
      // i. e.
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

And Webpack config:

```js
const baseConfig = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },

  // Source maps support ('inline-source-map' also works)
  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
        enforce: 'pre'
      }
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'manifest'
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'initial'
        }
      }
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'assets')
      }
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      CANVAS_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true),
      WEBGL_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    new MiniHtmlWebpackPlugin({
      context: {
        title: 'Phaser game'
      },
      // FIXME: CSS-loader and default minithmlwebpack template would probably handle this better
      template: ({js, title, publicPath } ) =>
        `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <title>${title}</title>
              <style type = "text/css">
                body {
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                  }
                  canvas {
                    display:block;
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                  }
              </style>
            </head>
            <body>
             ${generateJSReferences(js, publicPath)}
            </body>
          </html>
        `
    })
  ]
};

function getTestConfig() {
  const config = _.cloneDeep(baseConfig);
  delete config.entry;
  return config;
}
```

The `getTestConfig()` function changes the baseConfig slightly and passes the result to the Karma config.

Finally the dev dependencies in case there is something there which might help:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.10",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.3.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
    "mini-html-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.3",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
```

**So my question is, why tests do not seem to be able to import the modules I want to be tested? Is the problem in the Webpack, Karma or Typescript?**

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Typescript is not compiling the module you're trying to include (`foo`).  It would help to put together a small test case that reproduces the error, but you should check your `tsconfig.json` to ensure that it includes all the code that you want to be able to test.

I have a separate `tsconfig.test.json` that covers the main entry point for the application (`files: ["src/index.ts"]`) and also all the tests (`include: ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]`).  If you go this route, maybe make a `tsconfig.base.json` with common options, then include it in your production `tsconfig.json` as well as the test one.  You then need to point your Webpack config at the correct file, like

```js
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: {
      configFile: 'tsconfig.test.json',
    }
  }
},
```

You could set `configFile` to `tsconfig.json` by default, then your `getTestConfig()` function could alter it for use by `karma-webpack`.